# Python Pygame Error

Tags: python, pygame

so i've recently installed pygame because i want to start programming with it. Before writing code, i decided to just make sure its running fine by testing it in IDLE.

i ran

```
import pygame
```

no error

i ran

```
pygame.init()
```

and got the following error

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#1>", line 1, in <module>
    pygame.init()
AttributeError: module 'pygame' has no attribute 'init'
```

by doing some research i found out that it may be messing up the path, so i tried

```
pygame._path_
```

and got a similar error

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#2>", line 1, in <module>
    pygame._path_
AttributeError: module 'pygame' has no attribute '_path_'
```

and i can't figure out whats wrong. i've tried solutions in other questions but nothing works

im using 
Windows 10 Home 
Python 3.5.2 32 Bit
Pygame 1.9.2a0 for python 3.2 (but after looking up if it would work with python 3.5, i found resources saying it would)

i tried installing the 3.5 version as a .whl but it had its own host of problems and just decided to use the installer. is the error because of the mismatch between python versions and pygame versions, or is there something else i can try?

I have tried the following

```
pygame._path_
```

there is nothing else named pygame.py that would confuse the path
i used the installer 
i made sure there were no other versions of python/pygame installed

So are there any other solutions beyond the ones that i have tried to get this one working?

Thank you for your time.

EDIT 1: I have made sure that the only directory named pygame is the module.

Comment: Do you have a directory or file named pygame, it might conflict with the actual module

Comment: no i don't have anything name pygame that would conflict with the module.

Comment: type help(pygame) and explore what is there

Comment: @moniquepetrucci81 `pygame._path_` --> `pygame.__path__`. Magic methods have two underscores on either side of the method name. `dir(pygame)` will show you all the available methods including `init` if it's there (which it should be)

Comment: thank you for the help @jDo and now that i could check, it is set to the right path `_NamespacePath(['C:\\Users\\****\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python35-32\\lib\\site-packages\\pygame'])` that looks like the right path. anything else i can do to fix it? `dir(pygame) ` returned the following `['__doc__', '__loader__', '__name__', '__package__', '__path__', '__spec__']
`

Comment: i decided to check inside the pygame folder and all i found inside was __pycache__. that doesn't seem right

Comment: @moniquepetrucci81 I was about to say... There's supposed to be many (hundreds) of elements/methods in the list returned by `dir(pgame)`. I think you might have to re-install pygame.

Comment: @jDo i reinstalled pygame but ran into another issue. `import pygame` now returns `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#0>", line 1, in <module>
    import pygame
  File "C:\Users\****\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\pygame\__init__.py", line 95, in <module>
    from pygame.base import *
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.`

Comment: @moniquepetrucci81 You re-installed python, pygame or both? Did you follow the instructions on the [pygame website?](http://pygame.org/download.shtml) It says stuff like *"Get the version of pygame for your version of python.  You may need to uninstall old versions of pygame first.
NOTE: if you had pygame 1.7.1 installed already, please uninstall it first.  Either using the uninstall feature - or remove the files: c:\python25\lib\site-packages\pygame  ."*. I don't see a pygame version for Python 3.5 but try the newest one meant for Python 3.2

Comment: i reinstalled python 3.2 and pygame 3.2 and it works now. thank you! @jDo

Comment: do a new install of `pygame`

Answer (score 0):

## to finding the pygame path:

Magic methods have two underscores on either side of them.

## to the lack of pygame.init():

different software seem to be able to find different parts of pygame, because PyCharm cannot locate that function, but when running off the command line it operates perfectly. It may just be a fault of idle. Try running from the command line or double clicking the .py file, assuming it is associated with the interpreter. If that doesn't work, run the command
`python -m pip install --upgrade pygame`

Answer (score 0):

Have you installed pygame correctly.
Put this in your cd (command prompt) to check if you have installed pygame properly
`py -m pygame.examples.aliens`

If it gives a error then you should use the pip install function
`py -m pip install -U pygame --user`

If everything fails you can install an IDE. I would recommend pycharm https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/download/#section=windows
It is a free IDE and you can install pygame from there for a project
File --> Settings --> Project:(Name) --> Project Interpreter --> pip --> type pygame and install package.

[Pycharm pygame installation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I4cbv.png)